# How i can add Search Functionality in angular material select form component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material-6

I have `mat-select` Drop-down from angular material. 
It has list of state which is coming from API. It has more than 10 options in Drop-down.

**Todo :**

- I want Search option
  in `mat-select`.I used `mat-select search` from stackblitz but it's really difficult to understand.

Please suggest me simple way to do it.

My json code

```js
"{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 32,
      "name": "Andaman And Nicobar Islands"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "name": "Odisha"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "Puducherry"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "Uttar Pradesh"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Uttarakhand"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Andhra Pradesh"
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200
}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<mat-select-search [formControl]="formControlName"></mat-select-search>
```

Add this tag inside mat-select and follow the steps in app.component.ts of [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)